# Using rand() to select one of 2 specific numbers

Tags: select, random, numbers

I'm trying to call rand() to select one of two numbers, either a 1 or a 2.

so that: (pseudo)

```
//the first call might print 2
printf("%d",rand(1 or 2));  //prints 1, perhaps

//and the second call might print 2
printf("%d",rand(1 or 2));  //prints 2, perhaps
```

How can this be done?
Perhaps call these variables
int first=1;
int second=2;
and work from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want equal probability of each value, you could implement a simple function like this, which tests for `rand() < RAND_MAX / 2` to determine which of the two values to return:

```
int rand_1_2(int first, int second)
{
    return rand() < RAND_MAX / 2 ? first : second;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this I suppouse

```
double rnd = rand();
if(rnd < 1/2)
{
     printf("first");
}
else
{
     printf("second");
}
```